# Azure Storage account having container consisting of hierarchy folders :- Create automated email if file is not uploaded to selected folders

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Pretty new to Azure world ,however I have tried to googling this but haven't found a good way to go about this . Let me describe the problem

I have a storage account in Azure . In the container we are storing various data files . The files are stored in tree hierarchy of folders ( Parent-> year -> month -> day).Each day new files get uploaded to the specific day folder . If the file for that specific day is not uploaded I would like to drop email notification

Please let me know if you guys have an idea of how I can get this done

I have managed to do this
Basically use logic_app to monitor the storage account when blob is added to the storage account trigger an email

Is there are better way to do this ? I would like the logic to be if for specific folders in the container if there is no file by lets say 7pm everyday then drop email

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved?

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed reply , got caught up with another project ..but I got your approach will try it out ... i might have further follow up questions though . Once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
[image]

**This is some explanation of this simple logic :**

1. You can create a schedule to trigger this logic every day at 7 PM.
2. Use `List Blob` to check if there is any file in the folder let's
   say `/2021/03/17` so I use the expression to combine a path for
   every day checking:    `concat('/',utcNow('yyyy/MM/dd'))`
   In Azure storage, if there is no file uploaded to some path, this path not exists, `List Blob` will fail.
3. Send an email to someone if `List Blob` fails, set run after here so
   that this action will run only after `List Blob` fails:
   [image]

[image]

I have tested on my side and everything works as excepted :
[image]

[image]