# How to trigger Azure Logic App when a file is not being uploaded in Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cloud, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure blob storage where a file is automatically uploaded daily from an application. If it uploads a file daily, then it's fine. But if it doesn't upload a file in a day, then there is something wrong and it should send a notification. Is it possible to do it with Azure Logic App?

I can do it when a file is uploaded, but if it is not uploaded then I am not getting clue how to trigger that? So, any suggestions / ideas will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: Hi, in my case I used "Get Blob Metadata using path" and it worked as expected. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to know that my solution is helpful. Please click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in to accept it as an answer, it will help others and close this question  : )

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I have posted a solution that has a similar scenario to yours, pls see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664942/azure-storage-account-having-container-consisting-of-hierarchy-folders-create/) and let me know if you have any more questions :)